# SQL CAST or Convert to SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have a table called `T5VAULTSL3` in which my clients are under the column heading `VL3CLIENTNUM` and their cash amounts are under `VL3CONSIDERATION`;

`VL3CONSIDERATION` is showing object explorer as `(char(20), null)`

What I am trying to achieve is to group all `'Unique'` client numbers where the combined cash `(consideration) is > 10000`

I have tried;

```
SELECT vl3clientnum, CAST(VL3CONSIDERATION AS NUMERIC (20,2))
FROM T5VAULTSL3
WHERE Vl3CONSIDERATION > 10000
```

which returns

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' 0.00' to data type int.
```

So I tried

```
SELECT vl3clientnum, VL3CONSIDERATION
FROM T5VAULTSL3
WHERE CAST (Vl3CONSIDERATION AS NUMERIC (20,2)) > 10000
```

which returns

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

And

```
SELECT vl3clientnum, CAST (VL3CONSIDERATION AS NUMERIC (20,2)) AS CONSIDERATION
FROM T5VAULTSL3
WHERE CAST (Vl3CONSIDERATION AS NUMERIC (20,2)) > 10000
```

which returns

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Would I have to use the 'Declare' functionality and if so how?  A little stumped by this one...

Other attempts have included.

```
SELECT vl3clientnum, CAST (VL3CONSIDERATION AS NUMERIC (20,2))
FROM T5VAULTSL3
WHERE VL3CONSIDERATION > 10000
GROUP BY VL3CLIENTNUM, vl3consideration

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' 0.00' to data type int.


SELECT vl3clientnum, VL3CONSIDERATION
FROM T5VAULTSL3
WHERE CAST (VL3CONSIDERATION as NUMERIC(20,2)) > 10000
GROUP BY VL3CLIENTNUM, vl3consideration

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Absoultely perplexed!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason is that ' 0.00'  has a space in it. You better trim spaces:

```
CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(VL3CONSIDERATION)) AS NUMERIC (20,2))
```